# C++: Polymorphism: Call Super Function

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have an array of `Animal`.

An `Animal` says `"Animal"` by default.

I also have `Cat` which extends `Animal` and say `"Meow"` instead.

I also have `Dog` which extends `Animal` and say `"Woof"` instead.

What I want:

```
Animal* a[2];
a[0] = new Cat();
a[1] = new Dog();
a[0]->talk(); //Meow
a[1]->talk(); //Woof
```

What happens:

```
Animal* a[2];
a[0] = new Cat();
a[1] = new Dog();
a[0]->talk(); //Animal
a[1]->talk(); //Animal
```

---

//header

```
class Animal {
public:
    Animal();
    ~Animal();
    int talk() {return 0;}
};

class Cat : public  Animal {
public:
    Cat();
    ~Cat();
    int talk() {return 1;}
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    Dog();
    ~Dog();
    int talk() {return 2;}
};
```

//.cpp

```
void letsHear(Animal *a) {
    _LOG_INFO() << a->talk();
}

int main(){
    Animal* a[2];
    a[0] = (Animal *)new Cat();
    a[1] = (Animal *)new Dog();

    letsHear((Animal *)new Cat()); //0
    letsHear((Animal *)new Dog()); //0
    letsHear(new Animal()); //0
    letsHear(a[0]); //0
    letsHear(a[1]); //0
    return 0;
}
Cat::Cat() {}
Cat::~Cat(){}
Dog::Dog() {}
Dog::~Dog() {}
Animal::Animal() {}
Animal::~Animal() {}
```

Comment: This is not legitimate C++.

Comment: So pointers now work with `.`? Have you tried `a[1]->talk();`

Comment: Post all of your classes. It should work as expected, unless you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your base method `talk()` as `virtual` function.
Take a look at this example.

```
class Animal {
public:
    virtual void talk() {
        cout << "Animal" << endl;
    }
};

class Cat : public Animal {
public:
    void talk() {
        cout << "Meow" << endl;
    }
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    void talk() {
        cout << "Woof" << endl;
    }
};
```

And after that you can just call your method as in your example.

```
Animal *a[2];
a[0] = new Cat();
a[1] = new Dog();
a[0]->talk(); //Meow
a[1]->talk(); //Woof
```

Answer (score 3):

To get polymorphic behavior in C++, you must declare your function as `virtual`.  It's a good idea to make the destructor virtual too in any polymorphic base class:

```
class Animal {
public:
    Animal();
    virtual ~Animal();
    virtual int talk() {return 0;}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Static_and_dynamic_polymorphism), that is choose the function to call dynamically at runtime, based on the type of the object whose member function you want to call.

In C++, this is accomplished by using [virtual member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual). To use them, declare the corresponding member functions as `virtual` in your base class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct Animal {
    virtual void speak() const {
        cout << "Animal" << endl;
    }
    virtual ~Animal() {} // Better add this, too!
};
struct Cat : public Animal {
    virtual void speak() const override {
        cout << "Meow" << endl;
    }
};
struct Dog : public Animal {
    virtual void speak() const override {
        cout << "Wuff" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    array<unique_ptr<Animal>, 3> animals;
    animals[0] = make_unique<Cat>();
    animals[1] = make_unique<Dog>();
    animals[2] = make_unique<Animal>();
    for (auto const & a : animals) {
        a->speak();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[(Live example)](http://ideone.com/mskY6l)

If (any of) your deriving classes add member fields, and the ownership of any instance of these classes is in the hands of some pointer to the base type (as in my example), then you should follow aschelper's advice and make the bases destructor `virtual`. Otherwise you'll get memory leaks.

You can see that I'm using some concepts from the standard library in my code like `unique_ptr` and `array` as well as type inference in the `for` loop. Using these should be done whenever appropriate, using raw arrays / pointers is no more necessary in most cases and easily leads to memory management errors.